# Isogeny components of Jacobians of étale covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let us work over $\mathbb{C}$. Fix $X$ a smooth projective curve of genus at least $2$. For every simple abelian variety $A$, it is easy to come up with a ramified covering $Y\to X$ with a non-constant morphism $Y\to A$: just take any "diagonal" curve in $X\times A$.

What is known about the set of simple abelian varieties $A$ with an étale covering $Y\to X$ and a non-constant morphism $Y\to A$? Is it possible that it doesn't contain any abelian variety defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: Can you take just a curve $X\subset A$ and  an étale covering $f:A'\to A$? If this covering is not trivial over $X$, you can take some component of $f^{-1}(X)$ as $Y$.

Comment: $X$ is fixed, $A$ varies. Sorry, it was not clear. I reformulated the question

Comment: I think if $X$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, then all such $Y$ are parametrized by the torsion points of $\mathrm{Jac}X$ (hence also defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$). The morphism $Y\to A$ induces the morphism $\mathrm{Jac}Y \to A$. If you add the condition that $\mathrm{Jac}Y \to A$ is surjective, then all such $A$ are defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: @Teach: not all étale covers are parametrized by torsion point of ${\rm Jac} X$. Still, if $X$ is defined over $\overline{Q}$, $Y$ is defined over $\overline{Q}$ (this is the invariance of the étale fundamental group for extensions of algebraically closed fields). The surjectivity condition is automatic since $A$ is simple. Obiouvsly, if there exists a curve $X$ providing a counterexample to my second question, $X$ is not defined over $\overline{Q}$.

Comment: It should be possible to show that for $X$ a very general curve in $\mathcal M_g$, every étale covering $Y \to X$ has $J(Y)$ not containing any abelian variety defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. This is equivalent to saying that, for all finite groups $G$, the monodromy of the $H^1$ of the universal family over the moduli space of all $G$-coverings of a genus $g$ curve has no finite subrepresentation.

Comment: The statement Will S. makes is a very interesting one but I believe it remains a conjecture!  See Conj 1.2 in this 2011 paper of Putman and Weiland. https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2747

Comment: @JSE Interesting! I agree this may not be provable. I think I can show for $g$ sufficiently large depending on $G$ that the monoromy of the $H^1$ of the universal family over the moduli space of all $G$-coverings of a genus $g$ curve does not have any finite subrepresentation, but not necessarily for any fixed $g$.

Comment: @WillSawin [Grunewald-Larsen-Lubotzky-Malestein](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2593) do the case of $g$ greater than the number of generators of $G$, but, like most of the literature, they do it by proving that the monodromy is a lattice, which is a stronger conclusion and probably does require the stronger hypothesis of increasing $g$.

Comment: The statement is obviously false for genus 0 and obviously true for genus 1. You might want to generalize to incomplete curves. But then you might be surprised to learn that you have to exclude genus 1. In the appendix of the paper @JSE cites we give an example of a cover of an elliptic curve ramified in 1 point such that the new part of the Jacobian is independent of the choice of the elliptic curve (in particular defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$).

Comment: @WillSawin my student Lalit Jain's thesis (unfortunately not published) shows that the family of G-covers of genus g has l-adic monodromy as big as possible (i.e. as big as the centralizer of the G-action) when g >> |G|.  The main ingredient is the Fried-Conway-Parker-Volklein argument on connectedness of Hurwitz spaces when number of branch points -> oo (in this case various Hurwitz spaces for G semidirect (Z/NZ)^k)

Answer (score 1):

1. It can certainly happen that this class contains an abelian variety over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ without the curve $X$ being definable over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Indeed, start with an elliptic curve $E$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Let $Y\to E_{\mathbb{C}}$ be a ramified covering such that $Y$  is not definable over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. (You can achieve this by ramifying in enough transcendental points of $E$.) Now, take $Y=X$ and $A=E_{\mathbb{C}}$.
2. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Then, any  smooth proper curve $X$ over $k$ maps  non-trivially to a simple abelian variety $A$ over $k$. Indeed, consider the Abel-Jacobi map $X\to J(X)$. Then there is an isogeny $J(X) \to \prod_i A_i$, where each $A_i$ is a simple abelian variety over $k$. Now, choose $i$ such that the composition $X\to J(X) \to \prod_i A_i \to A_i$ is non-constant. Then $A_i$ is the $A$ you want.

This shows that, given any etale covering $Y$ of $X$, there is a simple abelian variety $A_Y$ such that $Y$ maps non-trivially to $A_Y$. It is not so clear to me whether you can say much about all these "simple" quotients of the Jacobian of $Y$.

*Final Remark.* Note that in $2$ the resulting $A$ might be the Jacobian of $X$. In this case, $A$ is definable over a number field if and only if $X$ is definable over a number field.

Comment: I didn't know that if the Jacobian is defined over a number field then the same holds for the curve, this is interesting, thanks. It follows from Torelli's theorem, right?

Comment: @GiulioBresciani Yes, it follows from the fact that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of smooth projective curves $C$ with the same (i.e., isomorphic) Jacobian. This strictly speaking is not Torelli's theorem, but can be deduced from it.

Comment: Actually in $2$, any $A_i$ works, because $\operatorname{Sym}^g X \to J(X)$ is surjective, so $\operatorname{Sym}^g X \to A_i$ is surjective, and thus $X \to A_i$ is nonconstant.

Answer (score 1):

Bogomolov and Tschinkel speculated that perhaps, for *every* pair of curves curve X,X' over $\bar{\mathbf{Q}}$, X admits an unramified cover which dominates X'.  And they prove this when X is hyperelliptic and X' is the curve with equation $y^2 = x^6 - 1$.

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202223

Comment: BTW, if this were true, you could use it to give a proof in the style of MInhyong Kim of the Mordell conjecture for curves over Q following the plan of a paper I wrote with Daniel Hast (actually, maybe it would give Mordell over any number field given stuff Hast and Dogra have done since then?)  But we don't know whether this speculation is true and it seems hard to tell.